# pointInPolygon function in cklickhouse for working with geographical coordinates

Tags: coordinates, clickhouse

I have a table in clickhouse - *telemetry_data* with two fields:
*lat(Float64)*
*lon(Float65)*
in which coordinates are stored.
I need to select records from this table in which the point with these coordinates will belong to the polygon on the plane.
The points describing this polygon are known.
Clickhouse has a function for that - [pointInPolygon](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/geo/coordinates/#pointinpolygon)
But I can't use it.
Here is my request:

```
select deviceId, lat, lon from `click-ss`.telemetry_data
WHERE 1=1
and (lat is not null and lon is not null)
and (lat != 0 and lon != 0)
and fix='1' --at that moment there were a sufficient number of satellites
and toTimeZone(eventDt, 'Europe/Moscow') BETWEEN '2022-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-07-01 23:59:59' 
and pointInPolygon(tuple(lat, lon),  array(tuple(55.736916, 37.365922), tuple(55.791985, 37.367902), tuple(55.872216, 37.399581), tuple(55.918200, 37.564574), tuple(55.896698, 37.713728), tuple(55.825806, 37.847042), tuple(55.646882, 37.848362), tuple(55.566931, 37.682709), tuple(55.584878, 37.501877), tuple(55.714776, 37.382372))) = 1
```

And the error I am getting:

*SQL Error [1002]: ClickHouse exception, code: 1002, host: 127.0.0.1, port: 17961; Code: 43. DB::Exception: Argument 1 for function pointInPolygon must contain numeric tuple at position 1: While processing (fix = '1') AND ((1 = 1) AND (lat IS NOT NULL) AND (lon IS NOT NULL) AND (lat != 0) AND (lon != 0) AND (toTimeZone(eventDt, 'Europe/Moscow') >= '2022-07-01 00:00:00') AND (toTimeZone(eventDt, 'Europe/Moscow') <= '2022-07-01 23:59:59') AND (pointInPolygon((lat, lon), [(55.736916, 37.365922), (55.791985, 37.367902), (55.872216, 37.399581), (55.9182, 37.564574), (55.896698, 37.713728), (55.825806, 37.847042), (55.646882, 37.848362), (55.566931, 37.682709), (55.584878, 37.501877), (55.714776, 37.382372)]) = 1) AND (1 = 1)). (ILLEGAL_TYPE_OF_ARGUMENT) (version 22.3.6.5 (official build))*

The error says that the Argument 1 for function pointInPolygon must contain numeric tuple at position 1

But if i look at the data type:

```
select deviceId, tuple(lat,lon) as geo, toTypeName(geo) from `click-ss`.telemetry_data
WHERE (lat != 0 and lon != 0)
```

I will get:

*device 1 (55.6637,37.6335)    Tuple(Nullable(Float64), Nullable(Float64))*

Please help me understand how to use this function correctly and where am i getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you don't need to specify the call to the [tuple()](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/tuple-functions/#tuple) function in your usage of pointInPolygon() (same thing for array()). For more examples, see the pointInPolygon() tests below (from ClickHouse Source Code):

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/9f5cd35a6963cc556a51218b46b0754dcac7306a/tests/queries/0_stateless/00500_point_in_polygon.sql

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly cast non-nullable type before passing it to pointInPolygon function. Ex:

```
pointInPolygon((toFloat64OrDefault(lat), toFloat64OrDefault(lon)), ... )
```

Even if you already have a condition `lat is not null and lon is not null`